# How to use Office365 plus addressing?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, alias

According to this change Office 365 should support email aliases using the + sign since September this year: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=59441

I have tested the feature on 2 office 365 environments, but in both cases Office 365 returns that it cannot find the user. [username]+[tag] wasn't found at [domain]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you have enabled this feature :AllowPlusAddressInRecipients

If not, this can be done through Powershell using the following command:

```
Set-OrganizationConfig -AllowPlusAddressInRecipients $true
```

More information:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-organizationconfig?view=exchange-ps

Comment: The parameter AllowPlusAddressInRecipients is not mentioned in the link you provided, why is that?

Comment: @MachielVisser - [Feature hasn’t actually been fully released.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=).  This is obviously only an educated guess as to the reason.  Nobody here will know the reason Microsoft support article is incomplete.  You should report the problem to Microsoft so it can be corrected.  9/22/2020 was a few weeks ago.